# How can I force Rails cache to not escape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm writing a string to my memcached using rails (Dalli), and then using node.js (node-memcached) to read the value, and Rails is writing to memcache with these extra prepended stuff. I also checked memcache using command line.

Writing with rails:

```
Rails.cache.write("test", 'helloworld' )
```

Reading from node.js:

```
// output
I"helloworld:ET
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that Dalli is calling `Marshal.dump('helloworld')` before writing the value to the cache.  To avoid this you'll need to interact with Dalli directly instead of going through `Rails.cache` then you can pass the `:raw => true` option to make Dalli store the exact value that you pass to it.

Something like this should do it:

```
dcache = Dalli::Client.new
dcache.set("test", 'helloworld', 0, :raw => true)
```

The third argument (`0`) is the ttl (time to live) value.  `0` means that the value never expires.  To expire values from the cache you can set a non-zero value which is the time measured in seconds.  So to expire the value after 5 minutes you could pass `300`.